# JSON parser error with java:

Tags: java, json, parsing

I would like to parse a json file, here is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class principale {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fichier ="C:\\listesanscoord.json";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("fichier");
        String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("oaci");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
        {
            String url = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");

        }
    }

}
```

and here is my json file:
[listesanscoord.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxn04jn4ep2gmig/listesanscoord.json?dl=0)
I have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:198)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:325)
    at metar.principale.main(principale.java:13)
```

Can someone help me please I am unable to find where is the problem, thank you.

Comment: I have seen your listesanscoord.json and the data it contains are not in json format, a lot of problem is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Extension to `@nogard` answer I detected that there is **error** in **JSON** text in your file ,JSON string are like **java map** or **javascript object** have key value pairs,in your file key is define wrongly, it should be in double quotes (" ") so key value pair will look like **"key":"value String"** or **"key":value Number**. For more info  look [link](http://docs.transifex.com/formats/json/).

After modification your json will look like below.

```
[
    {
        "oaci": "LFXA",
        "aeroport": "Aérodrome d'Ambérieu",
        "url": "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rodrome_d%27Amb%C3%A9rieu",
        "commune": "Chateau-Gaillard, Ambronay"
    }
    //more json objects 
]
```

if you modify your json file like above will resolve your problem.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxn04jn4ep2gmig/listesanscoord.json?dl=0 I changed my file as you told me, but still problem

Comment: yes this file has still some error try to past your json on [link](http://jsonlint.com/)  you will get  which lines contains errors.

Comment: oh yes sorry , look now .

Comment: your file looks fine ,this json should work fine with  java code.

Comment: this is not the case, error :Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:198)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:325)
 at metar.principale.main(principale.java:13)

Comment: As you can see your json is not a single json Object but instate it is aray of json object you need to create Object of  `JSONArray`  try 
`JSONArray jsonArrayObj = new JSONArray(jsonTxt); ` should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these lines:

```
String fichier ="C:\\listesanscoord.json";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("fichier");
```

You should normally pass content of the file, not just it's name (or "fichier"):

```
InputStream is = JsonParsing.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\listesanscoord.json");
String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );
```

Comment: Also the file listesanscoord.json is not in JSON

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not a json at all if it doesn't begin with **"{"**... that is the main interpretation of the Exception message.

Reformat the json doc and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty clear (for once!). The [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-fr.html) content must start with `{` or `[`, as it must define a root object or an array at least.

**EDIT**

The JSON content you posted is actually correct (good you verified with web utility [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)), as it defines an array of elements. The problem rises from the usage of Java API for JSON. Indeed, as shown by @nogard in his answer, the JSONObject String constructor is expecting some JSON content and NOT the file name.
(see [official doc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)). So your parser is trying to interpret the filename as some JSON content, thus failing (because the filename "`fichier`" is **NOT** a valid JSON string).

So you should grab the file contents before, via an inputstream for instance, and build your JSON object with the help of a serializing utility:

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(JsonParsing.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\listesanscoord.json"));
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( json );
```

Comment: look to my file now please 
it's ok? or not

Comment: @user26480 Yes, your file is now correct. The problem consists now in your JSON API usage, so I updated my answer accordingly.